# Why the vulgarism in Ezekiel 23:20?

Tags: ezekiel

Ezekiel 23:20 New International Version

> There she lusted after her lovers, whose genitals were like those of donkeys and whose emission was like that of horses.

Is this vulgarism in the Word of God?

Comment: Simply put - yes.

Comment: Neither the KJV nor Robert Young translate that way. _For she doted upon their paramours, whose flesh is as the flesh of asses, and whose issue is like the issue of horses._.

Comment: @NigelJ "Flesh" in the OT is a frequent euphemism for genitals, the "issue" clarifies that this is the intent. The verse is indeed intensely vulgar and it is apparently the Word of God, so we need to answer the question how this can be.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim no, we don't need to answer how this can be, on BH. If a question is not about hermeneutics (in this case it seems to be theology or apologetics) then it's off topic. I voted to close.

Comment: Well, OP is plainly asking if this is really vulgarity or not.  That seems objective enough.  Of course he wants to also know why it is there, and make sense of it.  The passage is almost as shocking today as it was for Ezekiel's audience.

Comment: Implied but not asked is, "How can the Word of God contain vulgarity?"  The law does not prohibit "using bad words" afaik, but prohibits "false witness", using the divine name without legitimate purpose ("in vain"), and cursing the deaf (not because it is cursing, but because the deaf have no way to respond to it).  I see this use of profanity as rather like God instructing Ezekiel in chapter 4, to eat a "crap sandwich" - bread and human excrement.  Ezekiel asks to be allowed to eat cow dung instead of human dung, and God agrees.  (Cow droppings are taharah / pure, human is tumah / unclean.)

Comment: God initially commanded to eat human excrement because of its prophetic symbolism - the people of the Covenant have made themselves thoroughly tumah / unclean.  God does not command Ezekiel to sin, He knows that Ezekiel will petition to substitute cow dung.  Without the initial command to eat human excrement, the prophetic significance would be lost.  In my opinion the use of profanity is the same.  Without it, the message would be watered down.  The shocking analogies to adultery are a critical element of these prophecies.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim Hebrew euphemisms should be translated into English euphemisms, not English vulgarities.

Comment: @wberry You have completely misunderstood God's request of Ezekiel. He was commanded to use human dung as fuel to bake his bread, which was a common practice among the gentile nations.

Comment: Interesting!  And even in modern times people do use "cow patties" to start fires sometimes.  I'll re-read this intently and likely delete / recompose my comments.

Comment: At https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftDEw8ZRa9o Douglas Wilson talks about (in the words of one commentor) "a theology of the righteous use of coarse language." He brings up this passage and others. Not sure I agree with Wilson wholly, but he does tackle the OP's implied issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Through the prophet Ezekiel *HaShem* expresses his extreme disgust for both the northern (Israel / Samaria) and southern (Judah) kingdoms, giving them the names *Aholah* (something like "tent-girl", presumably a term for a prostitute working out of a tent) and *Aholibah* ("[my] tent in her", which I take to be a reference to the Tabernacle among the people in the wilderness, but possibly also a double entendre of sexual slang).

The Covenant between Abraham and Elohim is likened to the consummation of a marriage (Ezk 16:8 - apparently marriages were consummated while partly clothed).  The two kingdoms' embrace of idolatrous worship of Molech and other false gods is likened to adultery (made plain in 23:37), described with the Hebrew word *to-avah* ("abomination"), and judgement is pronounced.

The use of profane metaphor in 23:20 is certainly interesting, but not unique.  Ezk 16 explores the same theme speaking of Judah's idolatrous influence from her neighbors.  Verses 25-26 are quite explicit:

> Thou hast built thy high place at every head of the way, and hast made
> thy beauty to be abhorred, and hast **opened thy feet to every one** that
> passed by, and multiplied thy whoredoms.  Thou hast also committed
> fornication with the Egyptians thy neighbours, **great of flesh**; and
> hast increased thy whoredoms, to provoke me to anger.

The powerful analogy of an adulterous wife who seeks well-endowed lovers but is so lustful that she will lie down with anyone who comes by is used to describe the people of the Covenant who have been promiscuous with other gods.

16:33 drives the point home even further:

> They give gifts to all whores: but thou givest thy gifts to all thy
> lovers, and hirest them, that they may come unto thee on every side
> for thy whoredom.

Most prostitutes *at least* get paid for what they do, but Jerusalem has so debauched herself that she has paid her idolatrous lovers instead, with precious gifts she was given by *HaShem*, increasing her shame even more.

The red hot anger of Elohim against the nation's persistent idolatry cannot be missed in reading through the prophet's message, brought not too many years before Babylon sacked and destroyed the Temple - as specifically predicted in later chapters.

It seems this message was meant to resemble the way a jealous husband, whose wife had taken other lovers time and time again, might react after being betrayed one too many times.  Such a husband might very well lose his temper, *justly* indulging in a profanity laced diatribe, a jealous rage, with name-calling and all kinds of angry threats.  Taken this way, the use of profane slang and explicit sexual imagery is hardly any surprise.

There is also 22:26:

> Her priests have violated my law, and have profaned mine holy things:
> they have put no difference between the holy and profane, neither have
> they shewed difference between the unclean and the clean, and have hid
> their eyes from my sabbaths, and I am profaned among them.

So as *HaShem* was "profaned among them", the prophet as messenger delivers a profane warning in turn.  Maybe that will get their attention, but if not, their failure to listen will only make more clear the justice of *HaShem*'s coming judgement.

Comment: Excellent. Appreciated. +1.